# System monitoring tool via command line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, monitoring, resources

Is there a command line tool for Windows XP to display system resources, like available memory usage, cpu, diskspace etc... Small and requires a non-install.

Best Regards,

Anders

Answer (score 1):

The built-in command 'tasklist' will give some information and has some useful command switches. Another option would be to run 'perfmon.msc' from the command line. This will open a window with useful information.

Another alternative, keeping it entirely command line based is [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) from Sysinternals. This provides access to a number of very powerful utilities.